# Limitar resultado a um aleatório

Tags: sql, random

Eu uso a query

```
SELECT * FROM mpbbolao WHERE eTIME1>=2 LIMIT 1
```

por exemplo. Para receber um resultado da query eu utilizo `LIMIT 1`. Tem como eu randomizar qual será esse "1" resultado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode utilizar utilizar uma ordenação randômica, assim terá o seu primeiro resultado também aleatório.

#### MySQL

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

[MySQL Reference Manual: Mathematical Functions (RAND())](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

#### PostgreSQL

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

[PostgreSQL Documentation: Mathematical Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-math.html)

#### Microsoft SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 1 column FROM table
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

[Microsoft Docs: NEWID() (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql)

#### IBM DB2

```
SELECT column, RAND() as IDX 
FROM table 
ORDER BY IDX FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

[IBM Knowledge Center: RAND](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000840.html)

#### Oracle

```
SELECT column FROM
( SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum = 1
```

[Oracle Docs: DBMS_RANDOM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#ARPLS040)

<sup>O código foi retirado [desta resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419/6241184).</sup>

Comment: Ja havia resolvido, mas obrigado por complementar! vai com certeza ajudar os outros!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, consegui resolver, segue a solução:

```
SELECT * FROM mpbbolao WHERE eTIME1>=2 order by rand() LIMIT 1
```

O "order by rand()" faz com que a ordem seja aleatoria, logo, o primeiro resultado também vai ser.